# Horizontal Flip animation ImageWidget Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I want to do Horizontal flip animation for CircularAvatar widget.. like below animation[image]
Like this i want to flip circularAvartar

I have tried

```
AnimationController _controller;

    AnimatedBuilder(
          animation: _controller,
          builder: (context, child){
            return Transform(
              transform: Matrix4.rotationY((1 - _controller.value ) * pi / 2),
            child: CircleAvatar(
            radius: PROFILE_PIC_RADIUS,
            backgroundImage: AssetImage(url),
           // backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
            ),
            );
          }
        ),

_controller.forward();
_controller.reverse();
```

But it is not working like below animation, i want animation like flipping coin in horizontal direction.. Please give any solution

Comment: Thanks, i will try it and update

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use library [flip_card](https://pub.dev/packages/flip_card).

Add this to pubspec.yaml :

```
dependencies:
  flip_card: ^0.4.4
```

Then run

```sh
flutter packages get
```

To use :

```dart
import 'package:flip_card/flip_card.dart';

FlipCard(
  direction: FlipDirection.HORIZONTAL, // default
  front: Container(
        child: Text('Front'),
    ),
    back: Container(
        child: Text('Back'),
    ),
);
```

Comment: Can't we do this with AnimatedContainer  widget  ??